# How to change the background color of an ExpandableListView in Android?

Tags: android, xml, background, expandablelistview

The title of my question pretty much sums up what I want to ask so In the description I will describe my question in detail.

So I have an ExpandableListView and it is printed out on the screen in black with white text inside. When I press on the list it is expended and I can select the details in it. It looks something like this:

```
|--------------------------|
|black color               | 
|   Title text(in white)   |
|                          |
|__________________________|
|  Item 1  (black text with white background)
|  Item 2                  |
|  Item N...               |
```

So my question is how to change the background color of the inside of the "Text Title" and put a limit for the number of symbols displayed in the title?

Here are my XML files:

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="228dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="485dp"          >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Item. XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"        
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Group.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#000000">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17dp"        
    android:textColor="#f4f4f4" 
    android:background="#323232"/>//this only changes some part of the background just around the text ONLY

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "put a limit for the number of symbols displayed in the title" ?

Comment: for example if the title is "I love to eat meat" on screen will appear
"I love to eat ..."

Comment: Add android:singleLine="true" property for textview

Comment: And to change background color, set background color for layout, not for textview

Comment: Nice this really did the trick the background color is changed! Thank you! But the number of symbols is still the same :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these properties in textview:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:maxLength="10" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Comment: Nice thank you and one last question is it possible to add "..." after the number of characters is reduced?

Comment: Well you are setting limit and if number of characters does not exceed  that limit it would print whole text. you can do this by overriding onTextChanged event in java and append "..." at the end of text

Answer (score 0):

In the expandablelistadapter :
In getGroupView under

```
  if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.listheader, null);
        }
```

: put this :

```
 convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

And to limit the text title characters use in the XML:

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/secondLineTextView" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:maxLines="1" 
android:maxLength="10" 
android:ellipsize="end"/>
```